# Microsoft Access: I need to map a description to a primary key

Tags: ms-access

This is homework, but I'm not asking for code, just help.

I need to set-up a database for a video rental store. The database has 4 tables to achieve normalization: Categories (the type of media), Rentals, Customers, and Media. This question is about the Category and Media tables.

The Media table looks like this:

- ID(Primary Key)
- Media Title
- Media Category(Related to the Primary Key of a Category)

And the Category table looks like:

- Category Code(Primary Key made up of a 3 letter code)
- Category Description(Text describing the category)

I created a form to add new media, and because there are so few categories, I decided to use a List Box to select the Category. The problem is, I want the List Box to display the Category description, but record the corresponding Category Code. I can't figure out how to do this though.

If I go into the List Box's data tab in the Property sheet, and set the "Row Source" as `SELECT Category.[Category Code] FROM Category`, it works fine, but shows the code instead of the description (obviously). If in the above statement I change `[Category Code]` to `[Category Description]` the box loads as I wanted, but I can't submit the form because it's expecting a Category Code, not a Description.

I need it to lookup the code based on the description that's selected, then record the found code. I've only been using Access for 2 days now, and I have no idea how to go about doing this. If anyone could point me in the correct directed, if be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to Set the Rowsource to:

`SELECT Category.[Category Code], Category.[Category Description] FROM Category`

Then in the property sheet, select the Format tab and set the `Column Count` parameter to 2 finally change the parameter: `Column Widths` to '0;2' which will hide the category code leaving only the category description. Finally check the 'Data' tab and the `Bound column` is one. You can then change the `Control Source` to relate to the field in the table you are adding the record to (Media Category).

Comment: Beautiful! This is far better then the mess of code that I tried to write. I'll try it on my break, thank you.

Comment: Is the `Bound Column` the column that it ultimately grabs the data from?

Comment: Yeah bound column dictates the column to use the value from

Answer (score 0):

You could create a query from both tables and include the Categorsy Description. You couls then create a form based on the query and the fields in your form could include the category.